# How to weight population size estimates?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, statistics

When estimating the size of a population, it's easy to figure out the relative probabilities of getting $r$ repeats in a sample, for a given population size. It's also easy to graph the individual probabilities for each population size, given $r$. However, there is one major obstacle to integration (to determine confidence intervals, etc.): how to horizontally scale the function before integration.

Suppose, using a simple capture/recapture method, I tag 20 individuals from a population of size $N$. When I recapture another group of 20 individuals, I find that there are five members already tagged. Given this, I would like to know $P(N>100)$. Would the function to be integrated use linear scaling (as with any other population parameter), like this?[image: linear scaling]
logarithmic scaling (to conform to Benford's Law), like this?[image: logarithmic scaling]
or something else entirely? (Yes, I did have to cheat a little with the second plot, regarding the axis labeling.)

(Plots generated using Mathematica.)

Comment: It seems that estimating pop size as in the 'capture-recapture problem' is essentially a discrete problem. Both the parameter (sample size $\tau$) and observed random variable ($X,$ the number of tagged individuals upon 'recapture') are discrete. If $c$ is the number captured and tagged and $r$ is the total nr re-capt, then the naive estimator of $\tau$ is to set $X/r = c/\tau$ so that $\hat \tau = cr/X.$ But, one might get $X = 0,$ so that $\hat \tau$ is infinite and $E(\hat \tau)$ does not exist. Please clarify with a specific exmp the purpose of your curves and why you want to integrate.

Comment: A Riemann sum of the function would suffice just as well, while also fulfilling the discrete requirement, but still allowing for weights. (At the scale I was using, it would be rather impractical to visually show that discrete nature, hence why I used the continuous function instead.)